# How to remove a course reversal (hold) on a Garmin 530W?

Tags: avionics

How can I remove a course reversal, (hold) from the FLP page on an RNAV approach ?  If I want to do a straight in (NoPT) it will not allow me to remove the hold without removing the whole waypoint.

Answer (score 2):

When loading a straight in approach into a GNS430/530, once you select the airport, approach and IAF, then hit ENT to either load approach or load the approach and activate, it will bring up a dialogue which asks if you want to fly a course reversal at the IAF.  If you select no, then no hold will be placed in the flight plan.  If you have entered the course reversal at the IAF for a straight in approach, you can still remove it by opening the FPL page, highlight the hold and press CLR to remove it.  It will ask you if you want to remove the course reversal one final time.  Select yes and press ENT.